# Toggling visibility of array of stateless react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to simply map over some data returned from an api and create a stateless component for each object returned. I want to be able to click on any of the components to toggle visibility of the rest of its data.

I have tried numerous ways to do it and keep hitting a brick wall, i've also scoured stack overflow and cannot seem to find an answer.

I have gotten it working by making them individual class components, however it seems like a lot of unnecessary code for just a toggle functionality.

Thank you in advance for any help or insight, here is a quick breakdown of what I have currently.

For clarification this is a simple app for me to learn about using react and an external api, it is not using redux.

fetched users in state of class component

```
class PersonList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      resource: []
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    let fetchedData = await API_Call("people");
    this.setState({ resource: fetchedData.results });
    while (fetchedData.next) {
      let req = await fetch(fetchedData.next);
      fetchedData = await req.json();
      this.setState({
        resource: [...this.state.resource, ...fetchedData.results]
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Then map over the results and render a component for each result

```
render() {
  const mappedPeople = this.state.resource.map((person, i) => (
    <Person key={i} {...person} />
  ));
  return <div>{mappedPeople}</div>;
}
```

Is there i can make each person component a stateless component with the ability to click on it and display the rest of the data? Here is what I have currently.

```
class Person extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      visibility: false
    };
  }
  toggleVisible = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      visibility: !prevState.visibility
    }));
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 onClick={this.toggleVisible}>{this.props.name}</h1>
        {this.state.visibility && (
          <div>
            <p>{this.props.height}</p>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Again thanks in advance for any insight or help!

Comment: Let me understand. This code you posted, works the way you want, but you'd like to refactor it into a stateless component?

Comment: Correct! It seems unnecessary to render 100 individual class components with state for such simple functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could keep an object `visible` in your parent component that will have  keys representing a person index and a value saying if the person is visible or not. This way you can toggle the person's index in this single object instead of having stateful child components.

**Example**

```
class PersonList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      resource: [],
      visible: {}
    };
  }

  // ...

  toggleVisibility = index => {
    this.setState(previousState => {
      const visible = { ...previousState.visibile };
      visible[index] = !visible[index];
      return { visible };
    });
  };

  render() {
    const mappedPeople = this.state.resource.map((person, i) => (
      <Person
        key={i}
        {...person}
        visible={this.state.visible[i]}
        onClick={() => this.toggleVisibility(i)}
      />
    ));
    return <div>{mappedPeople}</div>;
  }
}

const Person = (props) => (
  <div>
    <h1 onClick={props.onClick}>{props.name}</h1>
    {props.visible && (
      <div>
        <p>{props.height}</p>
      </div>
    )}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: As always, you are the faster one :) Also, no need to assume there is an `id` for `person`. I should remember doing those kind of things with indexes.

Comment: @devserkan Ids are for sure safer if they are present in the data, because order has to be the same when just using the index, but I went with index since I didn't see any ids in the question.

Comment: Actually, after writing this comment I think of that, too. Both method has some advantages. As you said, if there is no `id` or a unique value, indexes is the easy way I think. Thank you for your explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Similar idea with @Tholle but a different approach. Assuming there is an `id` in the `person` object we are changing `visibles` state and toggling `id`s.

```js
class PersonList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      resource: this.props.persons,
      visibles: {},
    }
  }

  toggleVisible = id => this.setState( prevState => ({
    visibles: { ...prevState.visibles, [id]: !prevState.visibles[id] },
  }))

  render() {
    const mappedPeople =
      this.state.resource.map((person, i) =>
        <Person
          key={person.id}
          visibles={this.state.visibles}
          toggleVisible={this.toggleVisible}
          {...person}
        />
      )
      
    return (
      <div>
        {mappedPeople}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const Person = (props) => {
  const handleVisible = () =>
    props.toggleVisible( props.id );
  
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 onClick={handleVisible}>
        {props.name}</h1>
      {props.visibles[props.id] &&
        <div>

          <p>{props.height}</p>
        </div>
      }
    </div>
  );
}

const persons = [
  { id: 1, name: "foo", height: 10 },
  { id: 2, name: "bar", height: 20 },
  { id: 3, name: "baz", height: 30 },
]

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<PersonList persons={persons} />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make sure your "this.state.resource" array has a visibility flag on each object:

```
this.state.resource = [
   { ..., visibility: true },
   { ..., visibility: false}
   ...
];
```

Do this by modifying your fetch a little bit.

```
let fetchedData = await API_Call("people");
this.setState({ 
    resource: fetchedData.results.map(p => ({...p, visiblity: true}))
});
```

Merge your Person component back into PersonList (like you are trying to do), and on your onclick, do this:

```
onClick={() => this.toggleVisible(i)}
```

Change toggleVisible() function to do the following.

```
toggleVisible = (idx) => {
    const personList = this.state.resource;
    personList[idx].visibility = !personList[idx].visibility;
    this.setState({ resource: personList });      
}
```

So now, when you are doing:

```
this.state.resource.map((person, i) => ...
```

... you have access to "person.visibility" and your onclick will toggle the particular index that is clicked.

I think that directly answers your question, however...

I would continue with breaking out Person into it's own component, it really is good practice!

Other than better organization, one of the main reason is to avoid lamdas in props (which i actually did above).  Since you need to do an onClick per index, you either need to use data attributes, or actually use React.Component for each person item.
You can research this a bit here:
https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md

BTW you can still create "components" that aren't "React.Component"s like this:

```
import React from 'react';

const Person = ({ exProp1, exProp2, exProp3}) => {
    return <div>{exProp1 + exProp2 + exProp3}</div>
}

Person.propTypes = {
    ...
}

export default Person;
```

As you can see, nothing is inheriting from React.Component, so you are getting the best of both worlds (create components without creating "Components").  I would lean towards this approach, vs putting everything inline.  But if your application is not extremely large and you just want to get it done, going with the first approach isn't terribly bad.